# I am unable to run a client/server program in php

Tags: php, sockets, client-server

This is the program I am trying to run:

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 25003;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
```

I enabled the PHP_socket option in WAMP but still I keep getting errors like unable to bind.  Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Firewall rules blocking the bind, or already have a program open listening on that port.

Comment: Yeah, try `telnet 127.0.0.1 25003` to see if something is already listening there. A backgrounded copy of this script, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

Possible problems:

1) There is another copy of the program running and locking the port.

2) Client tries to connect to 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'. On Windows, I noticed they're not necessarily the same. Depending on your network installation, "localhost" might be mapped to `::1` which is IPv6, while `127.0.0.1` is IPv4.

**TEST**

```
$ php -q test.php &
[1] 2855

# Now we try again a SECOND copy...
$ php -q test.php

PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in test.php on line 9
Could not bind to socket

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 25003
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
HELLO WORLD.
Client Message : HELLO WORLD..DLROW OLLEH
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: "'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1' (they're not necessarily the same)" - mind elaborating any case except lack of 'localhost' delegation at all?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, my own sad experience :-) -- on Windows application you really want never to use 'localhost'. Not to mention that some applications interpret "localhost" as something else altogether, e.g. MySQL takes it to mean "Local UNIX socket".